# Does using ReadWriteLock inside a synchronized method make sense?

Tags: java, locking

We have some code that implements a cache. All of the methods have the `synchronized` keyword, and also use a `ReadWriteLock` internally. Simplified example:

```
private final ReadWriteLock _rwLock = new ReadWriteLock();

public synchronized void setItem(final UUID id, final Object someObjToCache) {

    try {
        _rwLock.writeLock().lock();
        _innerCache.set(id, someObjToCache);
    } finally {
        _rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}

public synchronized Object getItem(final UUID id) {

    try {
        _rwLock.readLock().lock();
        return _innerCache.get(id);
    } finally {
        _rwLock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Is there any benefit to using both of these locking techniques? I expect it to be a read-mostly cache, so I would think that just using the `ReadWriteLock` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `ReadWriteLock` should be sufficient. Using it with `synchronized` does not make much sense in this case: `synchronized` means that only one thread can execute any synchronized method at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Using two locks will only help when you need to lock two resources at once.

I suspect you only need one lock, not two.  If you used a concurrent collection you might not need either.

```
final Map<UUID, Object> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void setItem(UUID id, Object obj) { cache.put(id, obj); }
public Object getItem(UUID id) { return cache.get(id); }
```